# Returning a vector of class POSIXct with vapply

Tags: r, posixct

I have list of dates having POSIXct class as follows (just a minimum working example):

```
L <- list(as.POSIXct("2012-12-12 12:12:12"), as.POSIXct("2012-12-12 12:12:12"))
```

I need to retrieve a vector of class POSIXct from it. This rules out lapply, and leaves me with sapply and vapply. I apply them as follows:

```
sapply(L, "[[", 1)
```

and this returns:

```
[1] 1355310732 1355310732
```

Converting this vector to POSIXct gives error as origin must be provided. I also tried vapply:

```
vapply(L, "[[", as.POSIXct(Sys.time()), 1)
```

but also get numeric vector returned:

```
[1] 1355310732 1355310732
```

Also unlist does not produce the desired POSIXct vector:

```
> unlist(L)
[1] 1355310732 1355310732
```

In short, how do I extract a list of POSIXct values into a POSIXct vector?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about `do.call`?

```
L <- list(as.POSIXct("2012-12-12 12:12:12"), as.POSIXct("2012-12-12 12:12:12"))
do.call(c, L) # Execute function c on a list L of arguments.
[1] "2012-12-12 12:12:12 CET" "2012-12-12 12:12:12 CET"
```

Comment: Indeed, as the manual on c function says: "All arguments are coerced to a common type...". Thanks.

Comment: This may change the time zone though if the original list had a tz attribute.`L <- list(as.POSIXct("2012-12-12 12:12:12", tz = "UTC"), as.POSIXct("2012-12-12 12:12:12", tz = "GMT"))` which is easy to fix if all the tz values are the same, e.g. by `.POSIXct(do.call(c, L), tz = "UTC")` but how can you keep the time zones if they are different?

Comment: @divibisan “`c` preserves attributes (like `class`)” — No, it does exactly the opposite, it *discards* them (and this is explicitly documented). But `POSIXct` provides its own `c` method to circumvent this. I’ve therefore rolled back your edit.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, I see that. Thanks, I'm really glad you caught that!

Comment: @divibisan Also, I apologise for my heavy-handed rollback. What you added did have value apart from the error. However, I’d actually suggest adding your own answer instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Don't worry about it! The fact that errors get smacked down is something I like about SO. I considered making an answer, but I don't have another approach to suggest, just a bit for additional info on the `do.call(c, L)` solution. That seems more worthy of an edit than a new question to me, though I'd be happy to hear otherwise from someone with more experience here.