# How to make vapply return a date vector?

Tags: r, loops, date

How can I make `vapply` return a date vector? (I think that's a different problem: [Returning a vector of class POSIXct with vapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859905/returning-a-vector-of-class-posixct-with-vapply) ):

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  as.Date(paste0("2000", sprintf("%02d", x), "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")
}

vapply(3:7, f1, as.Date("2000-01-01"))
# [1] 11017 11048 11078 11109 11139
```

Want:

```
# "2000-03-01" "2000-04-01"  "2000-05-01"  "2000-06-01"  "2000-07-01"
```

Comment: You can add `class(result) <- "Date"`

Comment: See what happens when you run `lapply(3:7, f1); sapply(3:7, f1, simplify = FALSE); sapply(3:7, f1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `apply` family functions drop `Date` class. Here is one way to do it:

```
do.call("c", lapply(3:7, f1))
```

You can also add `class(result) <- "Date"` after evaluating `vapply`.

Full version of `class(result) <- "Date"`:

```
result <- vapply(3:7, f1, numeric(1))
class(result) <- "Date"
result
# "2000-03-01" "2000-04-01" "2000-05-01" "2000-06-01" "2000-07-01"
```